# Blank Texture on Cycles GPU Baking (AMD)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking, gpu

I'm having problems for baking texture through GPU in Cycles.

> - Baking through CPU is working. (Very Slow...)
> - Render preview on 3D View through GPU is working.
> - Render through GPU is working.

Although I'm using `Bake Type` *Combined*, I'd also tried *Diffuse* and, unfortunately, got the same result.

My GPU is an AMD R9 390 (8Gb) with the last driver version (17.5.2) and I'm running Blender 2.78c on Windows 10.
Really appreciate some help.

My baking options:

[image: My baking options:]

My render options:

[image: My render options:]

My User Preferences:

[image: My User Preferences:]

Comment: Does CPU baking work as expected? AMD GPU computing is not as well supported or on par with NVidia feature set for the 2.78 series. Either use CPU or try a newer 2.79 testing builds at your own risk, OpenCL support as been thoroughly improved and is roughly on par with CUDA

Comment: The CPU baking is really fine, but slowly as expected. I'll give a try to 2.79 then, but I never tried testing builds... Could you please give me the download link !?

Comment: Check the "Bleeding Edge" link in red at the bottom of https://www.blender.org/download have in mind that these are unreleased testing versions, bugs and kinks are expected. Save your work often, make safe copies if necessary. And please, for the love of God, stay away from the 2.8 builds for the time being, they are not ready for end users yet, so do don't go complaining about errors and missing features.

Comment: The Blender-2.78-94a3bc6-win64 give me exactly the same results as the 2.78c. But Blender-2.78-58a434b-win64-vc14 works like a charm and it's noticeably way faster. Finally I got GPU baking on my Radeon !! Do you mind to post an answer, so I can mark as answered and solved !?

Comment: Posted below, you can thank AMD for their great support and dedication sponsoring development for improved Cycles OpenCL support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMD GPU computing is not as well supported as NVidia's solution, and definitely or on par in terms of feature set as of the Blender 2.78# series.

Either use CPU baking or try a newer 2.79 testing builds at your own risk. Cycles OpenCL support will be thoroughly improved and will roughly be on par with CUDA in terms of features and support as of Blender 2.79#.

At the date of writing Blender 2.79 is not released officiall yet so if you want to try it you must use development testing builds.
To do so head over to https://blender.org/download , and check the "Bleeding Edge" link in red at the bottom.

Have in mind that these are unreleased development versions, meant for testing purposes and not recommended for production; bugs and kinks are expected.
Save your work often, make backup copies of your files if necessary.

And please, for the love of God, **stay away from the 2.8 builds for the time being**, they are not ready for end users yet, not even for testing purposes, so do not ask about or report any errors or missing features you my find.